# I can't install any package in 15.10

Tags: software-installation, software-center, dpkg

Help me.. I can't install any packages in Ubuntu Software Center and `apt-get`

```
installArchives() failed: dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown option 'foreign-architecture'
Error in function:
```

Comment: **marked as [duplicate]**